# WordPress Migration on a Domain with different theme

Tags: wordpress, migration, themes

So i have a client who wants to migrate a website on a different domain. The website is Currently Running on Werkstatt theme but the Other website is a blog website running on Bingo Theme. The main Purpose of this is to add the blog contents of the website to the main website running on werkstatt theme.So as far as i know two themes cannot work. So what should i do to make the migration successful? I appreciate all of your Help.

Comment: Migrating the one with **Bingo theme** to a subdomain named **blog** will allow you to migrate the one with **Werkstatt theme** to main domain and have things working. You will need to make the layout uniform for domain and subdomain though.

Comment: I'm very sorry but i did not understand the layout uniform part. Did you mean designing the page?

Comment: Yes, keeping the header, footer and color scheme same on both domains so that it doe not appears as if you have left the parent website and are on different domain.

Comment: Ah yes, Understood. Thanks for your Help :D